# Lost connection to local server

Tags: networking, dns, cmd.exe

I wanted to connect to a local server on a domain without internet and found a way by changing the IP settings from "obtain an IP address automatically" to "use the following IP address" and giving it the actual IP address of my machine, then leaving the default gateway and preferred DNS server empty. It was working fine where I can reach my local server on the domain but with no internet but suddenly it stopped working and if I try to ping the domain it says `Ping request could not find host ..... Please check the name and try again` and if I make it with DHCP where the internet works then I can reach my server. Could anyone please advise?

[image]

Comment: What is the IP address of your server?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Is that okay to provide it on public? since it's a workplace server :/ Can you tell me steps you want to do and I can try them and tell you the results?

Comment: Is it on the same subnet as your local PC? i.e. is it a 192.168.1.something address? If so, it is safe to share it, as that is a local-only IP that cannot be accessed over the Internet.

Comment: Also are you saying that everything works fine when you just set it to Obtain an address automatically?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe no, it's not 192.xxx.xxx.xxx How I can get the subnet of the server if I know the server name suchas mycomp.ad.com?  Yes, it works when I set IP to DHCP and DNS to automatic.

Comment: Then what's your problem? Oh and if you are accessing it by name, then you WILL need a DNS server set, no way around it. DNS is what is responsible for converting a name to an address.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Yes, I used to set DNS and it used to work fine, but I don't set the Default Gateway. The problem now is that even though the DNS is set I cannot ping the server except when connected to the internet. So how I can get the subnet of my server using the IP?

Comment: I just was curious if the IP was a local IP. The subnet is irrelevant now that I've learned it is not a local IP.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe then why you think this happened?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author is connecting to an Enterprise network.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the server by name, and you set the DNS server field empty, then your computer has no way of looking up the server.

The actual connections are all done by IP address; DNS is what lets you specify a name, and converts it to an IP.

So you will need to have a DNS server set if you want to access it by name.

**EDIT**
And now that you said you left the default gateway empty, that also explains why it doesn't work. The default gateway is the IP address of your router, which is your connection to the Internet. And the DNS server, (even if not your local server), is on the Internet. Without a default gateway your computer can't even talk to the DNS server.

**So you will need both your DNS settings and default gateway setting to be able to talk to your server.**

Comment: So how I can connect to the server but not the internet?

Comment: @Tak Basically, you can't.

Comment: So how it was working for a long time like that?

Comment: @Tak Without all the information, which you don't want to share (understandably), I can't know.